# Can rvalue reference parameter ever be rvalue?

Tags: c++11

```
#include <utility> // for std::move
#include <iostream>

void some_function(int&& rvalue_ref) {
    std::cout << &rvalue_ref << std::endl; // rvalue_ref is always lvalue?
}

int main() {
    int x_val = 5;
    some_function(std::move(x_val)); // x_val is xvalue
    some_function(10); // 10 is prvalue

}
```

In regards to [this doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

1. In the above example when I pass xvalue (x_val, xvalue since `std::move` creates a soon to expire value) to `some_function` I can take the address hence I conclude that `rvalue_ref` is lvalue.
2. In the above example when I pass prvalue (10) to `some_function` I can again take the address. So, is `rvalue_ref` still lvalue even though I passed prvalue?

Is my assumption regarding case 2 correct? So, can rvalue reference parameter ever be rvalue?

Comment: Rule of thumb: anything that has a name is an lvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are giving your rvalue reference a name in the parameter list, it indeed becomes an lvalue. As @IgorTandetnik said - anything with a name can be assumed an lvalue. You do pass an rvalue to `some_function` - but at the same time you create an argument `rvalue_ref` which is now an lvalue (so you can actually call the address operator on it).

[This reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) provides a concise summary of what falls under rvalue or lvalue, however, you should read on it in an established C++ text too.

This is your example, modified with some useful learning points:

```
#include <utility> // for std::move
#include <iostream>

void some_function(int&& rvalue_ref) {
    std::cout << &rvalue_ref << std::endl; // rvalue_ref is always lvalue?
}

void some_function(int& lvalue_ref) {
    std::cout << "lvalue version: " << &lvalue_ref << std::endl; // rvalue_ref is always lvalue?
}


int some_other_function()
{
    return 42;
}

int main() {
    int x_val = 5, y_val = 10;
    some_function(std::move(x_val)); // x_val is xvalue
    some_function(10); // 10 is prvalue
    some_function(some_other_function()); // this is also prvalue
    some_function(y_val); // lvalue
}
```

I added an overload with an lvalue reference that will now be called for lvalues. This was really to demonstrate that you will often need two overloads - or at least the rvalue version. With this you can also see you are definitely sending `some_function` rvalues - if you comment out the rvalue overload this program will not compile. It will not be able to send the rvalues to the lvalue overload.

The other added function demonstrates a common useful source of rvalues that I added for completeness. lvalue call is to show that the lvalue reference overload is indeed called for lvalues when present.

Comment: Thank you  for the answer. By the way in the main since you did std::move(x_val) then again you do  some_function(x_val); // lvalue isn't x_value undefined here since std::move made it an expiring value?

Comment: Indeed, good point! Thank you. Fixing the answer. I rarely need to use move so I forgot. I do use the overloads all the time.